# Reverse the 0 padding of a DFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I am working on a rather large project and am stuck on a small part of it. The problem is as follows:

---

**Problem**

Let $x=\{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_{N-1}\}$ where $N$ is a power of two.

Let $X=\mathcal{F}(x)$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the DFT of X.

Given only $X$, I need to find a $Y$ such that $\mathcal{F}(Y)=\{x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_{\frac{N}{2}-1}, 0, 0, 0, ...\}$ in linear time ($\mathcal{O}(N)$ ).

**Example**

For example, let $x=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Then, $X=\{5 + 0 i, -1 - i, -1 + 0 i, -1 + I\}$.

I need a way to compute $Y=\mathcal{F}(\{1,2,0,0\})=\{1.5, 0.5 + i, -0.5, 0.5 - i\}$ in linear time.

**Maybe Useful Info**

I will just be performing convolutions between two vectors meaning that I don't care about the order of the elements.

---

I have not made much progress in this problem of mine. I believe that the answer may come from looking at the Cooley-Turkey FFT algorithm. A direct solution is preferable, but if you can think of a solution involving reordering the DFTs, storing them differently, etc., that would suffice. Finally, if you can think of a reason that this is not possible, please tell me so I don't waist my time.

Finally, I am in high school and while I am familiar with much of the mathematical notation, I am rather limited in much of the terminology. While I will work to understand your answers, please keep this in mind.

Thanks for your help, and have a great start of fall!

---

**Edit**
I was thinking that I could compute a "partial" DFT based on the fact that
$$X_k = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}x_ne^{-2\pi ikn/N} = \sum_{n=1}^{N/2-1}x_ne^{-2\pi ikn/N} + (-1)^k\sum_{n=1}^{N/2-1}x_{n+N/2}e^{-2\pi ikn/N}= X_{k,A} + (-1)^kX_{k,B}$$.

Assuming I want to add two vectors of this form, I can do so as follows:

$$\text{If }Z_k = X_k + Y_k$$
then
$$Z_{k,A} = X_{k,A}+Y_{k,A} \text{ and } Z_{k,B} = X_{k,B}+Y_{k,B}$$

This works in theory, but in practice, while $Z_{k,A} + (-1)^kZ_{k,B}$ has the correct values, $Z_{k,A}$ and $Z_{k,B}$ independently do not. Therefore, if I want to set $Z_{k,B}$ to $0$, $Z_{k,A} + (-1)^kZ_{k,B}$ does not correspond to vector I want it to. A solution using the evaluation of the two halves would mean there is an easy way to "redistribute" $Z_{k,A}$ and $Z_{k,B}$. However, I doubt there is a way to do this without computing any DFTs.

Comment: Just to clarify, given the Fourier transform $X = \mathcal F(x)$ of some sequence $x$, do you want an algorithm to find a sequence $Y$ such that $\mathcal F(Y) = x'$ or do you want an algorithm to find $Y = \mathcal F(x')$? (here $x'$ is the sequence $\{x_0, \ldots, x_{N/2 - 1}, 0, \ldots \}$, I assume you want to start at index $0$ or the length will be odd). It doesn't really make any difference since being able to do one means being able to do the other, but it would make it easier for people to tailor their answer to your specific needs.

Comment: Playing around with some toy examples, it seems relatively easy to get an expression for the coefficients of $Y = \mathcal F(x')$ in terms of those of $X = \mathcal F(x)$, however each coefficient depends on all coefficients of $X$ except one. There's probably some divide and conquer thing you can do here similarly to the Cooley-Turkey algorithm, however with how similar these calculations are to the DFT itself and the fact that it's still an open problem whether you can do FFT faster than $\mathcal O(N \log N)$, it feels like $\mathcal O(N)$ is rather optimistic.

Comment: Rushy, I want to find the ladder: $Y=\mathcal{F}(x')$. I agree that it is unlikely I will find a $\mathcal{O}(n)$ algorithm given only the Fourier coefficients. I was thinking about this and have come up with an idea that I appended to my original question.

Comment: I think in principle, and I think what you're trying to do, is to find a way to write the vector/sequence $\mathcal F(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} a_i\mathcal F(e_i)$ in terms of the basis $\mathcal F(e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the sequence that contains a $1$ at index $i$ and $0$ everywhere else.  Then by linearity you'd have $\mathcal F(x') = \sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1} a_i\mathcal F(e_i)$. However this change of basis matrix is precisely the inverse transform so the best this approach could do is $\mathcal O(N \log N)$.

Comment: Okay. Though I am a little disappointed, I appreciate your help. Thanks!